# Not getting proper result after connecting 4 tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am Working on Invoice and Payment Where I have 4 tables :

```
1. Client (Client Data i.e client_id, client_name)
2. Invoice (Invoice Data i.e invoice_no, client_id, invoice_date)
3. Invoice Data (invoice_no, product_name, qty, rate, tax)
4. Payment (Payment Data i.e invoice_no, paid_value, date)
```

I am connecting these tables but I am not getting the proper result. Below is the MySQL Statement:

```
SELECT invoices.invoice_no, clients.company_name,
SUM((((invoices_data.qty * invoices_data.rate) * (invoices_data.cgst + invoices_data.sgst + invoices_data.igst))/100) + (invoices_data.qty * invoices_data.rate)) AS invoice_value,
SUM(payments.value) AS paid_value
FROM invoices
INNER JOIN clients ON invoices.client_id = clients.id
INNER JOIN invoices_data ON invoices.invoice_no = invoices_data.invoice_no
LEFT JOIN payments ON payments.invoice_no = invoices.invoice_no
GROUP BY invoices.invoice_no
```

Result what i am getting :

```
invoice_no | company_name | invoice_value | paid_value
-------------------------------------------------------
INVML1     | RX Companies | 92978.1       | 6400
-------------------------------------------------------
INVML2     | Demo Client  | 2540          | NULL
```

The Above Result is Incorrect, The Total Invoice Value is 30992.7 and paid value is 3200.
Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: @scaisedge please share the answer

Comment: I don't understand  your comment ..,. i don't see  valid answer

Comment: If u know the answer, please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have more rows in join that produce a multiplication in the result for sum 
in these case you could try joining the subquery for sum

```
select  t1.invoice_no
  , clients.company_name
  , t1.invoice_value
  , t2.paid_value 
from clients 
inner join  (
  SELECT  invoices.client_id, invoices.invoice_no
       , SUM((((invoices_data.qty * invoices_data.rate) * 
        (invoices_data.cgst + invoices_data.sgst + invoices_data.igst))/100) + 
        (invoices_data.qty * invoices_data.rate)) AS invoice_value
  FROM invoices
  INNER JOIN invoices_data ON invoices.invoice_no = invoices_data.invoice_no
  group by invoices.invoice_no,  invoices.client_id  
) t1 on t1.client_id = clinents.id
left join  (
select  payments.invoice_no, SUM(payments.value) AS paid_value 
from  payments 
group by  payments.invoice_no
) t2 on t2.invoice_no = t1.invoice_no
```

Comment: answer  share  ..hope is useful  ... anyway without a proper data sample a.. i'm can't be sure this is the right answer

Comment: can u please share your email

Comment: @RahulKumarSharma  .. why you need  this  ???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201526/discussion-between-rahul-kumar-sharma-and-scaisedge).